# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'False' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape table data from web page by using below code but getting error:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'False'` in this line `data = (tabulate(df[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql') )`

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

res = requests.get("http://rerait.telangana.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTQmRGl2aXNpb249MSZVc2VySUQ9MjAyODcmUm9sZUlEPTEmQXBwSUQ9NSZBY3Rpb249U0VBUkNIJkNoYXJhY3RlckQ9MjImRXh0QXBwSUQ9")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

table_data = []

for i in range(len(soup.find_all('table'))):

    table = soup.find_all('table')[i] 
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    data = (tabulate(df[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql') )
    print (data)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_1.to_csv('D:/out_table.csv')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-128-30edd695db38>", line 15, in <module>
    data = (tabulate(df[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql') )

  File "D:\Conda\lib\site-packages\tabulate.py", line 1286, in tabulate
    for c, ct, fl_fmt, miss_v in zip(cols, coltypes, float_formats, missing_vals)]

  File "D:\Conda\lib\site-packages\tabulate.py", line 1286, in <listcomp>
    for c, ct, fl_fmt, miss_v in zip(cols, coltypes, float_formats, missing_vals)]

  File "D:\Conda\lib\site-packages\tabulate.py", line 1285, in <listcomp>
    cols = [[_format(v, ct, fl_fmt, miss_v, has_invisible) for v in c]

  File "D:\Conda\lib\site-packages\tabulate.py", line 754, in _format
    return format(float(val), floatfmt)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'False'
```

Comment: please post stacktrace as well

Comment: It's what it says -- you cannot convert the string `"False"` to a floating point number.

Comment: Can you check if your data contains NULL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826250/why-is-python-showing-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @SilverSlash, how to solve it?

Comment: I suggest you trace `table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. You can't convert the string `'False'` to `float`. What you *can* do is force your dataframe to numeric via [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), replacing non-convertible values with `NaN`, which *is* `float`:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(str(table))
dfs[0] = dfs[0].iloc[:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
data = tabulate(dfs[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql')
```

Comment: error:  ` File "<ipython-input-148-3637055db8e6>", line 17, in <module>
    df[0] = pd.to_numeric(df[0], errors='coerce')

  File "D:\Conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py", line 120, in to_numeric
    raise TypeError('arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series')

TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series `

Comment: @user10468005, See update. In general, the convention is for `df` to represent a **single** dataframe. Here, `pd.read_html` represents a **list** of dataframes (i.e. use `dfs`), so you need to adjust the logic slightly.

Comment: No Error but getting non: `+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    |   0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |
|----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
|  0 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+`

Comment: @user10468005, So there's something wrong with your input data. I can't help with that since you haven't provided any data. I suggest you need to sort this out at source or via upstream logic.

Comment: I have shared the link from there I am getting data. I am updating one table data

Comment: @user10468005, You are now asking a **different** question (i.e. "how can I debug my input data?"), I suggest you ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this rather than adding to this Q&A.